# Parsing JSON-RPC response with jquery undefined

Tags: jquery, json, plupload

In short, I need to get the filename from the below json string

```
{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "result" : {"cleanFileName": "1430648069-img003.jpg"}, "id" : "id"}
```

here is the code:

```
 init: {
        // FileUploaded is called when a file has been uploaded, and contains all info about the file
        FileUploaded: function(up, file, info) {
           var obj = JSON.parse(info.response);
           alert(obj.cleanFileName); 
        }
    }
```

I thought I could use the below to get the cleanFileName

```
var obj = JSON.parse(info.response);

           alert(obj.cleanFileName);
```

this just gives me an undefined alert, what am I missing?

Comment: alert (obj['result']['cleanFileName']);

Comment: that's the one - thanks :)

Comment: welcome. would you mind mark the comment as useful please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
alert (obj['result']['cleanFileName']);
```